# uwsgi throws IO error caused by uwsgi_response_write_body_do broken pipe

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

My application is a uwsgi+django setup.  I use gevent to do performance testing and run 1200 requests concurrently.  At this point, uwsgi will throw an IO error with the following log message:

```
uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 260]
IOError: write error
```

Django 1.4.0
uwsgi: 1.9.13
python: 2.6
TCP Listen queue: 1000

What is the cause of this broken pipe error?

Answer (score 50):

This can happen when NGINX started a request to uWSGI but uWSGI took too long to respond, then NGINX closes the connection to uWSGI. When uWSGI finally finishes, it tries to give it's response back to NGINX, but NGINX closed the connection earlier, so then uWSGI throws an I/O error.

So this could mean that your uWSGI process is taking too long.

Update:

uWSGI's Harakiri mode could be useful to automatically terminate such long taking processes if you want to:
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FAQ.html#what-is-harakiri-mode
You might not want to do this because a process might be finishing some long query or something which could be necessary.

Comment: I'm also getting similar error. Sat May 31 01:29:36 2014 - uwsgi_response_write_body_do(): Connection reset by peer [core/writer.c line 410] during POST /some/url/ (IP)
IOError: write error -- Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I found in /var/logs/nginx/error.log that nginx was trying to create a temp file and was failing due to permission denied error. I followed http://derekneely.com/2009/06/nginx-failed-13-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream/ to fix the permission issue.

Comment: @VijayendraBapte The link does not work anymore. What was the solution?

Comment: I also had this error and it showed up in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. Also permissions error due to nginx had only limited access to `uwsgi.socket` (I use unix sockets).

Answer (score 7):

This error means that the client has closed the connection before uWSGI/Django sends the response. It is generally caused by a timeout in the browser or web server frontend.

To fix it, you need to verify that your setup is correct. Look to see that all of your application's parts (including database adapters) are gevent-friendly. If they're not, you will get no advantage with gevent, and this could even lead to a decrease in performance.

In addition to this, you need to make sure that your database server is able to manage 1200 concurrent connections. If not, it may be ignoring connection attempts.

Comment: No, my application didn't use gevent, I just use gevent for testing.

Answer (score 3):

Now I am not recommending this without you considering your situation. But you could turn [uwsgi_ignore_client_abort](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_ignore_client_abort) to "on". With this turned on nginx will keep the aborted connection open until uwsgi returns. Why I don't recommend this completely is because this means an nginx connection will now be tied up until the request finishes. But really the uwsgi thread wasn't being aborted, so aborting the nginx connection early isn't really gaining you much in my opinion.