# 500 internal server error on certain page after a few hours

Tags: centos, nginx, python, uwsgi, flask

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error on a certain page of my site after a few hours of being up. I restart uWSGI instance with `uwsgi --ini /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/ers_portal_uwsgi.ini` and it works again for a few hours.

The rest of the site seems to be working. When I navigate to `my_table`, I am directed to the `login` page. But, I get the `500` error on my table page on login. I followed the [instructions here](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) to set up my nginx and uwsgi configs.

That is, I have `ers_portal_nginx.conf` located i my app folder that is symlinked to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`. I start my uWSGI "instance" (not sure what exactly to call it) in a `Screen` instance as mentioned above, with the `.ini` file located in my app folder

My `ers_portal_nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/run_web_uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

My `ers_portal_uwsgi.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
#user info
uid = metheuser
gid = ers_group

#application's base folder
base = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal

#python module to import
app = run_web
module = %(app)

home = %(base)/ers_portal_venv
pythonpath = %(base)

#socket file's location
socket = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/%n.sock

#permissions for the socket file
chmod-socket    = 666

#uwsgi varible only, does not relate to your flask application
callable = app

#location of log files
logto = /home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/logs/%n.log
```

Relevant parts of my `views.py`

```
data_modification_time = None
data = None
def reload_data():
    global data_modification_time, data, sites, column_names
    filename = '/home/metheuser/webapps/ers_portal/app/static/' + ec.dd_filename
    mtime = os.stat(filename).st_mtime
    if data_modification_time != mtime:
        data_modification_time = mtime
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = pickle.load(f)
    return data

@a bunch of authentication stuff...

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html",
                           title = 'Main',)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login stuff...

@app.route('/my_table')
@login_required
def my_table():
    print 'trying to access data table...'
    data = reload_data()
    return render_template("my_table.html",
                           title = "Rundata Viewer",
                           sts = sites,
                           cn = column_names,
                           data = data) #  dictionary of data
```

I installed nginx via yum [as described here](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install) (yesterday)
I am using uWSGI installed in my venv via pip
I am on CentOS 6

My uwsgi log shows:

```
Wed Jun 11 17:20:01 2014 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 287] during GET /whm-server-status (127.0.0.1)
IOError: write error
[pid: 9586|app: 0|req: 135/135] 127.0.0.1 () {24 vars in 292 bytes} [Wed Jun 11 17:20:01 2014] GET /whm-server-status => generated 0 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.0 404) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

When its working, the print statement in the `views` "`my_table`" route prints into the log file. But not once it stops working.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem might be a resource leak. Check if memory usage, number of open file descriptors, or some other resource usage grows over time.

Comment: @kasperd Since I am using `with` to open my files, shouldn't I be ok? I tried to set up MySQL logging, but that doesn't seem to be working. Would I just monitor memory usage with something like `htop`?

Comment: Seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504435/uwsgi-throws-io-error-caused-by-uwsgi-response-write-body-do-broken-pipe

Comment: @BrianLeach You can always check through `/proc/%d/fd` how many file descriptors the process has open. But the link from @Oldskool looks like a more likely explanation.