# nginx & uwsgi deploy django app get SIGPIPE 502 error

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, graphite, supervisord

I use nginx and uwsgi deploy my django webapp, the start few minutes all things well but after some time the ngnix will report 502 error and I check the uwsgi stderr log. there are some error marked `=> generated` & `SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request` such as blow error message:

```
>[pid: 27427|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.209.78.30 () {38 vars in 1030 bytes} [Mon Sep 29 15:46:00 2014] GET blabla...(just request url address) => generated 16018 bytes in 1428 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 157 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
Mon Sep 29 15:46:03 2014 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request blabla...(just request url address) (ip 10.209.78.30) !!!
Mon Sep 29 15:46:03 2014 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 287] during GET blabla...(just request url address) (10.209.78.30)
IOError: write error
[pid: 27425|app: 0|req: 1/2] 10.209.78.30 () {38 vars in 2050 bytes} [Mon Sep 29 15:46:00 2014] GET blabla...(just request url address) => generated 0 bytes in 3578 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Mon Sep 29 15:46:04 2014 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request blabla...(just request url address) (ip 10.217.95.130) !!!
Mon Sep 29 15:46:04 2014 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 287] during GET blabla...(just request url address) (10.217.95.130)
IOError: write error
[pid: 27426|app: 0|req: 1/3] 10.217.95.130 () {38 vars in 1871 bytes} [Mon Sep 29 15:46:00 2014] GET blabla...(just request url address) => generated 0 bytes in 4415 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
Mon Sep 29 15:46:05 2014 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request blabla...(just request url address) (ip 10.217.95.130) !!!
Mon Sep 29 15:46:05 2014 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 287] during GET blabla...(just request url address) (10.217.95.130)
IOError: write error
```

I replace the request url by blabla...

My nginx.conf is bleow:

location / {

```
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, OPTIONS";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "origin, authorization, accept";

    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/djangoapp.sock;
    include uwsgi_params;
}
```

uWSGI launch command:

`uwsgi --socket /tmp/djangoapp.sock -p 10 --wsgi-file /opt/graphite/conf/graphite_wsgi.py --chmod-socket=666`

Comment: [This similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504435/uwsgi-throws-io-error-caused-by-uwsgi-response-write-body-do-broken-pipe) suggests that your app may be taking too long to respond - does that sound plausible?