# Nginx is giving uWSGI very old requests?

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, unix-socket

I'm seeing a weird situation where either Nginx or uwsgi seems to be building up a long queue of incoming requests, and attempting to process them long after the client connection timed out. I'd like to understand and stop that behavior. Here's more info:

**My Setup**

My server uses Nginx to pass HTTPS POST requests to uWSGI and Flask via a Unix file socket. I have basically the default configurations on everything.

I have a Python client sending 3 requests per second to that server.

**The Problem**

After running the client for about 4 hours, the client machine started reporting that all the connections were timing out. (It uses the Python requests library with a 7-second timeout.) About 10 minutes later, the behavior changed: the connections began failing with 502 Bad Gateway.

I powered off the client. But for about 10 minutes AFTER powering off the client, the server-side uWSGI logs showed uWSGI attempting to answer requests from that client! And `top` showed uWSGI using 100% CPU (25% per worker).

During those 10 minutes, each `uwsgi.log` entry looked like this:

`Thu May 25 07:36:37 2017 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /api/polldata (ip 98.210.18.212) !!!
Thu May 25 07:36:37 2017 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/polldata (98.210.18.212)
IOError: write error
[pid: 34|app: 0|req: 645/12472] 98.210.18.212 () {42 vars in 588 bytes} [Thu May 25 07:36:08 2017] POST /api/polldata => generated 0 bytes in 28345 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 0)`

And the Nginx `error.log` shows a lot of this:

`2017/05/25 08:10:29 [error] 36#36: *35037 connect() to unix:/srv/my_server/myproject.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 98.210.18.212, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/polldata HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/srv/my_server/myproject.sock:", host: "example.com:5000"`

After about 10 minutes the uWSGI activity stops. When I turn the client back on, Nginx happily accepts the POST requests, but uWSGI gives the same "writing to a closed pipe" error on every request, as if it's permanently broken somehow. Restarting the webserver's docker container does not fix the problem, but rebooting the host machine fixes it.

**Theories**

In the default Nginx -> socket -> uWSGI configuration, is there a long queue of requests with no timeout? I looked in the uWSGI docs and I saw a bunch of configurable timeouts, but all default to around 60 seconds, so I can't understand how I'm seeing 10-minute-old requests being handled. I haven't changed any default timeout settings.

The application uses almost all the 1GB RAM in my small dev server, so I think resource limits may be triggering the behavior.

Either way, I'd like to change my configuration so that requests > 30 seconds old get dropped with a 500 error, rather than getting processed by uWSGI. I'd appreciate any advice on how to do that, and theories on what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue downstream on the uWSGI side.

It sounds like your backend code may be faulty in that it [takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20526299/1122270) to process the requests, does not implement any sort of rate limiting for the requests, and does not properly catch if any of the underlying connections have been terminated (hence, you're receiving the errors that your code tries to write to closed pipelines, and possibly even start processing new requests long after the underlying connections have been terminated).

- As per http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2013-February/005362.html, you might want to abort processing within your backend `if not uwsgi.is_connected(uwsgi.connection_fd())`.
- You might want to explore https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#harakiri.
- As last resort, as per [Re: Understanding "proxy_ignore_client_abort" functionality (2014)](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,253026,253029#msg-253029), you might want to change [`uwsgi_ignore_client_abort`](http://nginx.org/r/uwsgi_ignore_client_abort) from `off` to `on` in order to not drop the ongoing uWSGI connections that have already been passed to the upstream (even if the client does subsequently disconnect) in order to not receive the closed pipe errors from uWSGI, as well as to enforce any possible concurrent connection limits within nginx itself (otherwise, the connections to uWSGI will get dropped by nginx should the client disconnect, and nginx would have no clue how many requests are being queued up within uWSGI for subsequent processing).

Comment: Thanks; those explanations make sense -- basically nginx is filling uwsgi's socket with requests, ignoring the fact that uwsgi isn't processing them.  Strange that the default configuration allows that; I would have thought uwsgi would at least have a timeout based on how long the incoming request has been sitting in the socket. The `ignore_client_abort` setting is interesting; I'll try that. (The harakiri setting didn't solve it.)

Comment: @Luke, yeah, I think, basically, uWSGI makes a conservative assumption that you might not want to have any requests dropped, even if clients do disconnect right away; it would seem that, at the very least, you might want to amend your backend to at least check that the client is still connected at least when you start processing the request.  Also, related, an interesting read about dropping the late requests in their entirety — http://ferd.ca/rtb-where-erlang-blooms.html

Comment: I finally got a better understanding of this -- I used the `siege` command-line tool to hit my dev server with a bunch of requests for an endpoint that just slept 10 seconds then returned. Turns out that someone else had adjusted the uwsgi max queue length to be very large. So uwsgi workers were getting fed very old requests (once the request is on the uwsgi queue, an nginx connection timeout doesn't remove it). Solution was: 1) shorten the queue, and 2) make nginx add a header with a timestamp to each request, and add Django middleware to drop old requests (immediately return a 400).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like DoS attack on Nginx uWSGI returning 100% CPU usage with Nginx 502, 504, 500. IP spoofing is common in DoS attack. Exclude by checking the logs.