# What are the default values of uwsgi config?

Tags: python, config, uwsgi

I am trying to troubleshoot my uwsgi app not holding on load. Keep in mind I'm quite new to app development, not to mention uwsgi itself. 
I found a lot of examples of useful things to check (e.g. [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html) or [here](https://www.techatbloomberg.com/blog/configuring-uwsgi-production-deployment/)), and `uwsgi --help | grep "relevant-option-name"` gave me good info on how to get the desired behaviour.

However I couldn't find the default values used by uwsgi for options like `--reload-on-rss` or `--max-requests`. Where can I find them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out default values are indicated in help **when they exist** and can be accessed through `uwsgi --help | grep 'default'` which yields a list with e.g. things like

```
    --worker-reload-mercy                 set the maximum time (in seconds) a worker can take to reload/shutdown (default is 60)
```

Configuration arguments not listed by this are simply not used when not specified, hence no default value.

Comments on [Recommended settings for uwsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591103/recommended-settings-for-uwsgi) gave it to me.